SharePoint Online Edit Document Properties but not Document Content
I have a document library where users have Contribute access. The document library has a Approval Status column which contains the status. The approvers are meant to view(not edit) the document and Provide approval. If approved the Approval Status column becomes Approved. The approvers need to be given Contribute access such that they can modify the approval status column. However this permission level also allows them to edit the file which ideally should not happen. Is there any way we can give a user read access on the document and edit access on the properties.

You have full control as the library owner, and your user has the Contribute permission on this library. Who is the approver? Is it the user who is requesting to be granted Contribute permission? Please provide more details on your request.

Approver is a person who will view the document and Approve/Reject. If that person approves the Status Column becomes "Approved"
